# Error with FindMinimum. The Message is FindMinimum::cnpcons

Tags: performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization

I want to run a rather demanding check of feasibility.

I have 3565 non-negativity constraints for my variables, and one that makes them sum to a certain budget they shall not surpass. I also have one inequality constraint that calculates whether or not, for a given set of values of the variables, a given constant is smaller or larger than the [Gini coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gini_coefficient) for the current data.

The expression looks like this:

```
GWSUB[y_, ES_, t_, w_, k_] := Module[{yt, ytw, Gini},
    yt = (y + t) / ES;
    ytw = (w*(y + t)) / ES;
    Gini = -k*(2*(Plus @@ w)*(Plus @@ ytw)) + 
             Sum[ (w[[j]]*(Plus @@ Abs[ytw - yt[[j]]*w]), {j, 1, Length[y]}
  ]
```

Here are the meanings of the symbols I used:

- The vector of variables is $t$.
- $y$ is a vector of incomes.
- $w$ is a vector of weights.
- `ES` is a separate vector of weights.
- $k$ defines the candidate value for the Gini coefficient and is a scalar.

The vectors are all of length 3565.

I then tried to run the `FindMinimum` command. Here `T` is the vector of variables `t[i]`. `TC` are the non-negativity constraints on the `t[i]`. 
`B` is the budget (a scalar).

```
FindMinimum[
  {
   0*(Plus @@ T),
   GWSUB[Y, ES, T, W, 0.3294] <= 0, 
   Sequence[TC], (Plus @@ T) == B
  },
  T, 
  Method -> "InteriorPoint", WorkingPrecision -> 7, MaxIterations -> 500
]
```

I get an error of this form:

> FindMinimum::cnpcons: Could not process the constraints ...

and then it refers to the GWSUB expression.

Does this mean that I cannot run the computation with the current machine?
Is there a way to simplify the expression, so that *Mathematica* will process it?

### **My Value Configuration**

To reproduce my results you will need the following data set:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/qni6zoecmdm9p1x/data.xls?dl=0

Then import the data set and use the following set up:

```
Y = Table[dta[[j]][[1]], {j, 1, 100}]; 
W = Table[dta[[j]][[3]], {j, 1, Length[Y]}];
ES = Table[dta[[j]][[2]], {j, 1, Length[Y]}]; 
T = Table[t[i], {i, 1, Length[Y]}]; 
TC = Table[t[i] >= 0., {i, 1, Length[Y]}]; 
TS =  Table[{t[i], 0.}, {i, 1, Length[Y]}];
B = 2791967732
```

### **Minor Update**

I have tried to let `FindMinimum` only evaluate numerically by compiling the aforementioned `GWSUB` function with `"RuntimeOptions" -> {"EvaluateSymbolically" -> False}`. While the calculations of the `GWSUB` function are faster, the call to `FindMinimum` still resulted in the same error message.

Comment: Can you please post your *Mathematica* code in actual copy-and-pastable form, properly-formatted? Using Tex to display your *Mathematica* code is inconvenient, because we can't just copy and paste into our own versions of *Mathematica*. In addition, we'll probably need *all* the definitions, e.g. the definition for `T` and `TC`.

Comment: In addition, there are some very strange things going on. Why do you have both `0*(Plus @@ T)` and `(Plus @@ T) == B` as equations? The first isn't even an equation (and it evaluates to zero anyway). Can you check your syntax and your definitions first?

Comment: Hello March,it is a feasibility problem. That means, I am minimizing zero subject to constraints, so that any value satisfying the constraints minimizes the expression.

Comment: Ok, is this acceptable regarding the formatting and the definitions?

Comment: It's not only acceptable, it's *preferred*. Anyway, I don't think `FindMinimum` will work for a feasibility problem. I think you might want to look at `FindInstance` instead.

Comment: Oh, it worked. When I tried it on a smaller dataset, I got sensible results. But I'll try FindInstance.

Comment: Are both weights sums equal 1?

Comment: The problem is linear and much more simple if you could suppose $\forall _{\{i,j\}}\left(i<j\Rightarrow
   \frac{t(i)+y(i)}{\text{es}(i)}-\frac{t(j)+y(j)}{\text{es}(j)}>0\right)$ Please check it

Comment: Hello Dr. Belisarius. The weights do not sum to 1, but sum to the number of individuals in the population.  Also the stipulation you made is not necessarily true for all i and j. It certainly is true that you could derive an ordering $$\forall_{i,j} (i<j \Rightarrow y(i)-y(j)>0)$$, but depending on how large the population weight is and how large ES is, your statement above will not hold.

Comment: You need to start the names of your correspondents with an "at sign" to get the other party pinged. As in `@option_select`

Comment: @Dr.belisarius Ok, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Clearly you're interested in a response, but without working code, it's hard for people to guess what the problem is.  Is there a simple example, say values for `Y`, `ES`, `W`, `TC` and `B`, that reproduces the problem?  You could try `FindRoot`....

Comment: @MichaelE2 I'll add the precise configuration of values that are giving me the problem.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Ok, done. Now everybody can run the FindMinimum command and try for themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have not figured out what the specific error code is but I have reformulated the objective function so that MMA can actually process the constraint.

The objective function now is:

```
 ObJ[y_, ES_, t_, w_, k_] := Module[{yt, ytw, Gini},
 yt = (y + t)/ES;
 ytw = (w*(y + t))/ES;
 If[-(k*(2*(Plus @@ w)*(Plus @@ ytw))) +Sum[ (w[[j]]*(Plus  @@ Abs[ytw - yt[[j]]*w]),{j,1,Lentgth[y]}] <= 0
, 0, \[Infinity] ]
 ]
```

Now the constraint is part of the objective function and `FindMinimum` seems to process this just fine.

However, the processing speed is still very slow.
I have run the same program in Matlab and it was worked out in a couple of minutes. MMA is still running.

Comment: Can you rewrite your `Sum` as a `Total`? And is there a way that you could re-write the Gini expression to use a squared value rather than the `Abs` function?

Comment: Hi @MarcoB, I don't think that I can get around using at least one `sum` without resorting to a covariance formulation of the Gini, which I do not want to use, since that would depend on assigning ranks, which is quite cumbersome with equivalence scales and weights. The idea of using a squared value is interesting. I haven't tried that.